# View custom column

Tags: sharepoint-2007

SHAREPOINT 2007

I've created a customer site column.  When the user creates a webparts page the column must be populated.

What I want to do is have the value of this column automatically appear on the web page. 
This should not be that hard.....

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the out of the box input form, for them to fill in the data, the column will show up there automatically.  If you are referring to a list view that is already on a page, you will need to edit the page, modify the webpart settings and customize the view (or simply pick an existing view that has the column added to it.)

When you put a list on a web part page, the list view format is psuedo copied to the page in that the page will not reflect and changes to the view that existed when it was put on the page, which is why you either have to reselect the default view or else customize the view of the webpart on the page.